# Is Jenkins and Dokku more or less the same?

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, docker, dokku

I have seen [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) being used as CI for Docker containers. Is [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) also a CI platform like Jenkins?

If, what is the difference when I want to do CI with Docker containers for a PHP application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you maybe confusing drone with Dokku? Dokku is a platform for execution of heroku apps drone is a docker based CI. I don't know much about drone but since docker can't be run inside a docker container without some hacking you are better off sticking to a traditional CI like jenkins, bamboo, team city or such.

Comment: I think you are right =) Reading the Heroku website and Wikipedia site, it is not clear when Heroku should be used. When does it make sense to use Heroku for an app?

Comment: Heroku should come in when you are done and ready to release your application. Although I am not familiar enough with Heroku to know if it supports docker containers natively. Id does support php without docker though.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from Usman Ismail's answer...

If you look at `dokku-alt`, the distinction is less clear.  In particular dokku-alt allows you to use a Dockerfile for the build rather than buildstep, so it's not specific to Heroku like apps.

Dokku-alt is not in itself a CI system, but out of the box it does verify that the build completes without error before it's deployed, and using git hooks you could connect in your test-suite to run on every `git push` and block deployment when it fails.

CI typically is a bit more than this.  You'd normally have multiple deployments for test, staging and live, and to some extent it also encompasses a set of practices.  Dokku-alt gives you some very useful parts of CI, and a fairly clear path to building more of it fairly easily, but it's not a complete CI system in itself.

You might well prefer to keep your main git repository elsewhere, and keep jenkins in the picture for automating transfer to dokku-alt.

Comment: Note: at this point, I'd consider dokku-alt abandoned and dokku to be a suitable choice in any of the points you've made :)

Comment: Agreed.  A pretty poor showing from the author of dokku-alt really.  Moving on to other projects is one thing, but the complete lack of communication and failure to let anyone take over is unimpressive.

Comment: Life happens, and I don't blame him too much for moving on. Shame he couldn't point his users to a maintained project though.

Comment: Sure, he can move on, but a message to his users and allowing a co-maintainer would have made all the difference.